# How to generate dSYM files without xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, dsym

Let's say I'm using autotools to build a product on Mac OS X with clang. How can I "manually" tell it to use right debugging format and the strip to a valid dSYM file?

Is there any specification of the dSYM bundle and files?

Answer (score 12):

Figured out by looking the output of the Xcode:

```
dsymutil <binary> -o <binary>.dSYM
strip -S <binary>
```